# Cannot find Column[ABC] C#

Tags: c#, combobox

I am putting a data from a datasource into a Combo box. Even though I am getting error I am still getting the required result.

```
cbxdata.DisplayMember = "ABC";
cbxdataDatasource = datatable;
```

My data table has two records of ABC but am getting error and two items in combobox. What could be the reason behind this error.

Error I am getting is 
Cannot find Column[ABC].

Comment: `two records of ABC` ? `but am getting error` what? message?

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: meaning it has two rows in my datatable and that means two values in datatable for ABC

Comment: Are you sure that your datatable has a COLUMN named ABC that is assigned to the DisplayMember of the combo?

Comment: Yes I am sure if I was wrong I wont be able to fill my combo box I am not able to upload pics or else I would show you

Answer (score 0):

DisplayMember should be set to the name of the column in the DataTable that will provide the  ComboBox items text.  The error indicates that you do not have a column in the DataTable named "ABC".

Comment: I am getting error but am also getting required results